Looking for fast ways to process 2 billion rows of data
I have over 1 billion rows of "pairs" of numbers that all contain 10 pairs.
I have another set of "pairs" say "edges".
I need to loop through the edges. For each edge, I need to check if the edge appears in one of the rows. Then I need to update that row by replacing the pair with some symbols if the edge is in the row.
Are there quick ways to do this? I am ok if the most efficient software costs some money. Also, the software would need to be complex enough for me to write code / update the lines as above.
Approximately how long would you say this process will take? What factors will it depend on?
Thank you for any help!
I have tried using the standard python module as follows:
    for edge in edges:

        pair = (min(edge), max(edge))
        str_pair = f'({str(pair[0])}, {str(pair[1])})'

        print(str_pair)

        with open(buffer_path, 'r+', buffering=1024*1024) as file:
            while True:
                line_start = file.tell()
                line = file.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                else:
                    if str_pair in set(line.split(".")):
                        new_line = line.replace(str_pair, len(str_pair) * '_')
                        file.seek(line_start)
                        file.write(new_line)
                    else:
                        file.seek(line_start)
                        file.write(line) 

But this is far too slow

Instead of making us guess how long would it take, why don;t you run a smaller batch, measure the time and extrapolate how much the whole batch will take?  We don't know what computer you have, and the running time will entirely depend on the power of the computer you are running the code.

One obvious optimization would be to skip the last else. You don’t need to write the unchanged line back to the file. If the majority of lines don’t need to be changed, this could already speed up the entire thing by orders of magnitude.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example with a subset of your input data and expected output. It's not clear from what you've shown so far what you're trying to do

You should also probably turn this around. Don't read through the entire file again and again for each edge. Instead, read a line from the file, then determine if any one of your edges is in it. Disk I/O is the bottleneck here, you don't want to do that more than you have to.

Assuming you have enough RAM, you could load the 'edges' into a dictionary and do fast random look-up for each pair in the rows in your file requiring only a single pass. Still might take a few hours.

I benchmarked using golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
  "sync"
  "time"
 )

 const numWorkers = 12 // Number of goroutines (workers) to run

 func main() {
  // Define the number of records (2 billion)
  // numRecords := 2_000_000_000
  numRecords := 100_000_000

  // Start benchmark
  simulateAndBenchmark(numRecords)
 }

 // Worker function to process a batch of records
 func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, targetPair, replacement string) {
  defer wg.Done()

  for job := range jobs {
    // Simulate a record with the target pair
    record := fmt.Sprintf("Record %d: %s some other data", job, targetPair)

    // Check if the record contains the target pair
    if strings.Contains(record, targetPair) {
        // Replace the target pair with underscores
        record = strings.ReplaceAll(record, targetPair, replacement)
    }

    // For demonstration purposes, we won't print the record, but you could process it here
    // fmt.Printf("Worker %d processed record %d\n", id, job)
    }
  }

func simulateAndBenchmark(numRecords int) {
  // Start timer
  start := time.Now()

  // Target string to replace
  targetPair := "(1, 2)"
  replacement := strings.Repeat("_", len(targetPair))

  // Channel to distribute jobs
  jobs := make(chan int, numWorkers)

  // WaitGroup to synchronize all workers
  var wg sync.WaitGroup

  // Start the worker pool
  for i := 1; i <= numWorkers; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(i, jobs, &wg, targetPair, replacement)
  }

  // Send jobs (records) to workers
  for i := 0; i < numRecords; i++ {
    jobs <- i
  }

  // Close the jobs channel to signal no more work
  close(jobs)

  // Wait for all workers to finish
  wg.Wait()

  // Record the time taken
  elapsed := time.Since(start)
  fmt.Printf("Processed %d records in %s using %d workers\n", numRecords, elapsed, numWorkers)
}

On average the process takes about 34 minutes on a 16GB 3200 MT/s RAM with
CPU
11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz

Base speed: 2.42 GHz
Sockets:    1
Cores:  4
Logical processors: 8
Virtualisation: Enabled
L1 cache:   320 KB
L2 cache:   5.0 MB
L3 cache:   8.0 MB

Utilisation 11%
Speed   2.32 GHz
Up time 0:22:05:24
Processes   359
Threads 4952
Handles 291775

For the results are as follows for different workers and different ranges
 Processed 1000000 records in 724.045ms using 8 workers 
 Processed 1000000 records in 446.1339ms using 12 workers   
 Processed 10000000 records in 4.6425266s using 12 workers 
 Processed 100000000 records in 52.8540714s using 12 workers
 Processed 2000000000 records in 32m42.0265975s using 8 workers 

But it would be even faster in C++ since it offers direct memory access.
I would perfer you using a better GPU and memory to make things even faster. The tests above are from a mere laptop with a basic GPU.

amazing work, thanks

I think you can try to use some Python's libraries dedicated to scientific computing or datascience such as numpy or pandas and use HDF5 files to store/retrieve your data using h5py.
For example, your first lines could be replaced by:
import numpy as np
edge = np.asarray(edge) # edge as numpy array of shape (n, 10)
pair_max = edge.max(axis=0)
pair_min = edge.min(axis=0)
pair = np.stack([pair_min, pair_max], axis=-1)


You can use np.isin to check if an element is in another array.
As a rule of thumb, try to avoid for loops and string conversion (and intermediary I/O operations if not needed), and replace them with vectorized operations.
Otherwise I'm afraid that you'll have to switch to more performant langages such as C/C++, etc.
